# Telnet session already in use, Unable to create session

Tags: session, telnet

I have created a telnet session and without exiting properly I closed terminal window. Now I am unable to connect again and can not make telnet session with appliance. I am getting following error message at console.

> > > ### Error Message
> > >
> > > This connection is in use. User(s) currently connected: NONE@99.
> > >       You need privilege to make a simultaneous session.
> > >       Connection closed by foreign host.

How can i close previous session which was created, or how can i overcome this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the process really still exists with:

`ps aux | grep telnet`

Then `kill` it:

`killall telnet`

Comment: This assumes having access to the server.

Comment: Yes. As you said if don't have access to the server I think you don't have much to do.

Comment: I was commenting because he specifically said "Now I am unable to connect again" - and so your answer is not exactly useful.

Comment: @guntbert agreed. I did not consider all options, I thought he had access to it but it is not very clear. So would be better to take into account the worst result.